# update local variable with function before trigger the tableview delegate in swift

Tags: ios, swift, variables, delegates, tableview

Hi I have the following code where I use a callback function to grab some data in my Model (where I do API calls to get some data). The data is passed to this viewController. So I want to use the data to update a local variable so that my tableView data source delegate can be populated with the data I retrieved in the Model.

but seems the local variable can never be updated... can anyone tell me how to resolve this? Thanks.

```
class MyAutoListViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    
    var vehicleManager = VehicleManager()
    var newData: VehicleData?
    
    
    //var numberOfVehicle: Int = 0
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        vehicleManager.retrieveUserVehicle()
        vehicleManager.onDataUpdate = { [weak self] (data: VehicleData) in
            
            self?.useData(data: data)
            
            print(">>>>>>>>new data: \(self?.newData)")
        }
        

        
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView() //remove empty tableView cells
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: Constants.vehicleListCellNibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: Constants.vehicleListToBeInsuredIdentifier)
        tableView.reloadData()
        
        
    }
    
    func useData(data: VehicleData) {
        let newData = data
        print(">>>newData is: \(newData)")
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    
    
}

//MARK: - TableView extensions


extension MyAutoListViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return newData?._embedded.userVehicles.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.vehicleListToBeInsuredIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! VehicleListTableViewCell
        cell.vehicleName.text = newData?._embedded.userVehicles[indexPath.row].vehicle.brand
        
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

here is a pic of my debug output:

I can print out the newData, it's in the useData func, but the local variable cannot be updated... it's still nil.

[image]

Comment: You write `let newData = data`, this `let newData` is a NEW variable, a local one. You wanted to write either `self.newData = data`, or `newData = data` (prefers using `self` for now, if it's still unclear for you, it's okay to do the explicit). And, after that line, you might want to do: `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }`

Comment: Thanks Larme, what a stupid mistake I made ... fxxxk I spent 2 hours on it ...